# HTML5 - img alignment centre not working

Tags: html, image, alignment

I am trying to align my profile picture in the middle of my webpage yet cannot seem to get it working. I have attempted both align="middle" & float methods yet it still refuses to leave the left hand side.

The code I have attempted to use (HTML5) is

```
<header>
        <h1> Luke Johnson Portfolio</h1>

        <div class="image-cropper" style="text-align">
            <img src="lukeprofile.jpg" align="center" alt="Luke Profile Pic" class="rounded" />

        </div>
</header>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`align` attribute for the image is aligning it relativelly to the text or other images on webpage (for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp).

**And notice** (info from w3schools):

*"The align attribute of  is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."*

So `align` attribute will not do the trick in your case, you can center image using:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

instead. Here is an example:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1> Luke Johnson Portfolio</h1>
  <div class="image-cropper" style="text-align">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000017423279/1a6d6f295da9f97bb576ff486ed81389_400x400.png" alt="Luke Profile Pic" class="rounded" />
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! sorry so late on the reply - appreciate everyone who provided help towards this

Answer (score 0):

You Have misused the inline style tag, proper use would be as follows:

`<div class="image-cropper" style="text-align: center">
    <img src="lukeprofile.jpg" alt="Luke Profile Pic" class="rounded" />
</div>`

I could help you more if I had the URL to the website.

Answer (score 0):

Compatibility Notes
The align attribute of img tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

For the image to align middle, top, or bottom use the CSS property.